# how to set current quarter in Superset?

Tags: apache-superset

I want to set current quarter dynamically, e.g [2021-01-01 ~ 2021-04-01)

Does superset support it? if so how to config it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `Last` vs `Previous` and date range control in general has been a source of confusion for my users.

`Last Quarter` just shows the last 3 months [because it's a quarter of a year?].

It would be great to have options like `Week to date`, `Month/Period to date`, `Quarter to date`, etc...

Another issue is that each company may define their quarters/periods on different starting dates, depending on their fiscal calendar.

As a stop-gap, I've done the following.

- enriched the underlying dataset to have additional columns like `period_start_date` and `fiscal_quarter_start_date`.
- created a `fiscal_dates` table that contains a list of every day over the years I need to query. The columns correlate with date columns in my other tables, like `dob`, `fiscal_week_start_date`, `period_start_date`, `fiscal_quarter_start_date` . I created this table in postgres using `generate series`
- created a new virtual dataset that contains the column `period_start_date`, that shows the last 4 years of period start dates.
- use a `value` native filter to select from the list of dates.
- make the values sorted descending, and default value as "first item in list".

This allows the user to select all records that occur in the same quarter/period, with a default of the current quarter.

Answer (score 1):

The tentative [apache/superset#17416](https://github.com/apache/superset/pull/17416) pull request should remedy this problem, i.e., for the QTD you would simply specify the `START` as `datetrunc(datetime("now"), quarter)` and leave the `END` undefined.

Comment: This is implemented in versions 1.5.0+.  Current version as of this comment is 2.0.0, this worked great on Time Range -> Advanced.